# ChartJS - TypeError: Cannot read property '_model' of null - Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, charts, chart.js, subscribe

I'm on a project to display data in a ChartJS graph in real time.
From a service, I get data from an external webserver. I success to have 6 array (they are changing in real time) with always 10 values :

```
for (const module of parsedListResults) {
  this._consoAir[module.id - 1].shift();
  this._consoAir[module.id - 1].push(module.consoAir);
}
```

So every 5 secondes, the array of data are changing :

```
0: (10) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6.865885, 6.865885, 6.865885, 6.865885]
1: (10) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6.865885, 6.865885, 6.865885, 6.865885]
2: (10) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6.865885, 6.865885, 6.865885, 6.865885]
3: (10) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6.865885, 6.865885, 6.865885, 6.865885]
4: (10) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6.865885, 6.865885, 6.865885, 6.865885]
5: (10) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4.654, 4.654, 4.654, 4.654, _chartjs: {…}, push: ƒ, pop: ƒ, shift: ƒ, splice: ƒ, …]
length: 6
```

The graph is display on a page with an id. For the page 3, we have localhost:4200/lines/3, so we want the 3rd array for the graph, and I do that here :

```
import {Component, Input, OnDestroy, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { ChartType } from 'chart.js';
import { LineService } from '../services/line.service';
import {ActivatedRoute, Data} from '@angular/router';
import {combineLatest, Subscription} from 'rxjs';
import {filter, map} from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-conso-graph',
  templateUrl: './conso-graph.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./conso-graph.component.scss']
})
export class ConsoGraphComponent implements OnDestroy{

  lineSubscription: Subscription;
  id: number;
  consoAir: number;
  chartType: ChartType;
  chartOptions: any;
  _time: any[] = Array(10).fill(0);
  _consoAir: any[];
  dataType: Data;

  constructor(private lineService: LineService,
              private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.chartIt();
    setInterval(() => {
     this.chartIt();
    }, 5000);
  }


  _focusedData$ = combineLatest(
    this.lineService.lineSubject.pipe(filter(x => x.length > 0)),
    this.route.params.pipe(filter(x => !!x.id), map(x => x.id - 1))
  ).pipe(
    map(([csvs, id]) => csvs[id])
  );


  gestionData(): void {
    this.lineSubscription = this._focusedData$.subscribe(x => this.id = x.id);
    this._consoAir = this.lineService._consoAir;
  }


  async chartIt(): Promise<void> {
    await this.gestionData();

    this.chartType = 'line';
    this.dataType = [{
      data: this._consoAir[this.id - 1],
      label: 'Consommation Air'
    }];

    console.log(this._consoAir[this.id - 1]);
  }

  chartClicked(e: any): void { }
  chartHovered(e: any): void { }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.lineSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }

}
```

And for the HTML, we have :

```
<div class="doubleTrp">
    <canvas baseChart
            [chartType]="chartType"
            [datasets]="dataType"
            [labels]="this._time"
            [colors]="[{
              backgroundColor: ['rgb(255, 182, 0)'],
              hoverBackgroundColor: ['rgb(185, 30, 30)'],
              borderWidth: 1
            }]"
            [options]="{
              responsive: true,
              cutoutPercentage: 100,
              animation: {
                duration: 0
              },
              title : {
                display: true,
                text: 'Consommation Air',
                fontSize: 25
              }
            }"
            [legend]="true"
            (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)"
            (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)">
    </canvas>
</div>
```

The probleme isn't when I am in page with the graph is display, the probleme is when I go to other page (like localhost4200/), I have this error "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '_model' of null" and I don't know how I can resolve that.

Thanks for your responses, I'm completely lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the problems, I write the array of data in my html template ...

I replace this :

```
this.dataType = [{
  data: this._consoAir[this.id - 1],
  label: 'Consommation Air'
}];
```

By this in HTML :

```
<canvas baseChart
            [datasets]="[{
      data: this._consoAir[0],
            this._consoAir[1],
            ...
            this._consoAir[9],
      label: 'Consommation Air'
    }]"
...
```